# Brutal synth drop

Tags: bass, kick, synthesizer

I just want to know what kind of sound is that (even if both are a bit different) and how to do it if possible (different layers and sounds used, especially the synth). I have Sylenth1 and Massive. Thanks!

@ 1 minute

@ 2 minutes

Comment: Honestly? Why are you asking someone else? Isn't it more fun to discover it by yourself after a few hours of playing and having fun with your synths?

Comment: Read/watch some tutorials on youtube and go and experiment. Also look into Side-chain compression.

Comment: Maybe because I am not enough knowledgeable yet?

Comment: Maybe I'm a grumpy old guy, but in my day it was something that you needed to figure out for yourself. And I'd get a kick out of it when I nailed the sound. But glad that you've gotten an answer that's helpful for you. Good luck

Comment: @ArnoudTraa: If everyone needed to figure out every interesting thing by themselves, there wouldn't be much point in a Q&A site like this...

Comment: perhaps my 'comment' is a bit simplistic. what i meant to say was this: you can ask someone else how it's done, but if you figure it out yourself, you'll learn much more and 'figuring it out' is fun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not as easy as you hope!

The Idea behind those huge Electro sounds is layering + distortion + short reverbs and other stereo enhancer.

Typicaly you build a solid bass layer + midrange bass or saw bass  + supersaw sounds (chords) + vibrato lead (melody).

The spooky lead sound that plays the melody in the benassi song might be a supersaw layered with a pitch envelope sound.

To get the basic electro saw bass (bass layer), I give you a short tutorial for the midrange and supersaw sounds you need to search some tutorials.

Ok get a synth up and use a standard saw with no filter and 100% sustain on the amp envelope. After that use a eq and remove everything under c.a. 200 Hz. then via bell eqs boost a little bit somewhere around 450 hz, cut somewhere around 1 kHz and boost by a HUGE amount (15-30 db) between 2 and 3 kHz. This will sound like shit now until you crank this into some distortion unit. (ohmicide,camelphat, whoknowswhat) This will create that cutting aggressive saw sound. Finish up the sound by limiting, bit crushing, flanging and reverberation.

Then use a lowpased saw wave to layer with that to get a solid bass synth.

Comment: Nice! This is the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: No Problem: Also try to use the Dimension expander plugin on this website. Its free and emulates the dimension expander of massive. Use it on the midrange bass layer to give it some huge stereo image. http://www.xferrecords.com/freeware/